# Django how to delete from ManyToManyField with extra field?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

In my django app I have models set up similar to these models on the django site - [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Further down the page, I read

> The remove() method is disabled for similar reasons. However, the clear() method can be used to remove all many-to-many relationships for an instance:

If the remove method is disabled then how do I remove an object from a manytomany field? It says that I can use the clear method to remove everything but I only want to remove one specific element from the manytomany field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the instance on the intermediary model.

From the example provided in djangoproject:

```
m_qs = Membership.objects.filter(person=person, group=group) #or some other logic to filter
try:
    m = m_qs.get() #assuming queryset returns only 1 element
    m.delete()
except:
    pass #handle more gracefully
```

Comment: ok thanks. In ipython I can also see a delete() method as well. Is there a difference between delete and remove? Should I use one over the other?

Comment: sorry.. my mistake. Should have reviewed before posting. It is `delete()` not `remove()`